# Display nested files in children of element ui tree using vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, tree

I am using element ui tree for my vue application. I am implementing 'File browser' type system for my application. In here, files are nested into children.While clicking on child node those nested files or docs will be displaying right side in different container. I am not able to iterate through children and display those files.

```
**Here is the mocked data :**

data:[{
      id: 1,
      name: ‘Project A’,
      type: ‘folder’,
      children: [{
        id: 4,
        name: 'Project A-1’,
            type: ‘folder’,
        files: [
          {
            id: 9,
            pid: 4,
            name: ‘file 3-A’,
            type:’file’,
            description: ‘wifi’,
            country: ‘USA'
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            pid: 4,
            name: ‘file 3-B’,
            type:’file’,
            description: ‘VPN’,
            country: ‘USA'
          }
        ]
      }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Services’,
      type: 'folder',
      children:[],
      files: [
        {
          id: 5,
          name: ‘Services-1-A’,
          type:’file’,
          pid: 2,
          description: ‘VPN’,
          country: ‘AUS'
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: ‘Services-1-B’,
          type:’file’,
          pid: 2,
          description: ‘WIFI’,
          country: ‘AUS'
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Servers',
      type: 'folder’,
      children:[],
      files: [
        {
          id: 7,
          name: ‘Servers-1-A’,
          type: ‘file’,
          pid: 3,
          description: ‘VPN’,
          country: ‘CAD'
        },
        {
          id: 8,
          name: ‘Servers-1-B',
          type: ‘file’,
          pid: 3,
          description: ‘WIFI’,
          country: ‘CAD'
        }
      ]
    }]
```

**Here is my UI code**

```
<el-row>
                      <el-col :span="8" style="background: #f2f2f2">
                       <div class="folder-content">
                         <el-tree
                             node-key="id"
                             :data="data"
                             accordion
                             @node-click="nodeclicked"
                             ref="tree"
                             style="background: #f2f2f2"
                             highlight-current
                             >
                             <span class="custom-tree-node" slot-scope="{ node, data }">
                                 <span class="icon-folder">
                                  <i class="el-icon-folder" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                  <span class="icon-folder_text" @click="showFiles(data.id)">{{ data.name }}</span>
                                 </span>
                             </span>
                         </el-tree>
                       </div>
                     </el-col>
                     <el-col :span="16"><div class="entry-content">
                      <ul>
                       <li aria-expanded="false" v-for="(file,index) in files" :key="index">
                             <div class="folder__list"><input type="checkbox" :id= "file" :value="file" v-model="checkedFiles" @click="check">
                             <i class="el-icon-document" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                             <span class="folder__name">{{file}}</span></div>
                       </li>
                     </ul>
                       </div></el-col>
                   </el-row>
```

**Show files method:**

```
showFiles(id) {
 let f = this.data.filter(dataObject => {
    if (dataObject.children && dataObject.children.id === id) {
      return false
    } else if (!dataObject.children && dataObject.id === id) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  })[0]
  this.files = f.files
}
}
```

I am trying to do like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a bug in your filter function. Check  **line 3** :

```
showFiles(id) {
 let f = this.data.filter(dataObject => {
     //isn't this suppose to return true?
    if (dataObject.children && dataObject.children.id === id) {
      return false
    } else if (!dataObject.children && dataObject.id === id) {
      return false
    }
    return true
  })[0]
  this.files = f.files
}
```

Why using `filter()` method to search for single element? It will scan through all the elements. You could just `find()` instead to improve performance and better readable code.
Try this:

```
showFiles(id) {
    let f = this.data.find(dataObject => dataObject.id == id);
   //ensure node was returned
   if(f ){
     this.files = f.files
   }
}
```

However, You could try and do this in your component instead.
Add another property to the component's data object. Use the new property to hold the selected node.

```
  data(){
      //your mock data
      tree:[],
      //children files being displayed
      files:[]
    
  },
  methods:{
      showFiles(branch){
           this.files = branch.files;
      }
  }
```

Then pass the whole object to the method

```
<span class="icon-folder_text" @click="showFiles(data)">{{ data.name }}</span>
```

Comment: I am trying to modify by using your suggestion. Will you please elaborate that mentioned methods? I am not getting two same methods or changes.

Comment: Apparently, I gave you two different possible solutions.

Comment: First one: Edit your showFiles method

```
showFiles(id) {
    let f = this.data.find(dataObject => dataObject.id == id);
   //ensure node was returned
   if(f ){
     this.files = f.files
   }
}
````